# Zeroes of a polynomial. Evaluate an expression

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the zeros of the polynomial $7x^3+24x^2+2016x+i$. Evaluate $(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_2^2+x_3^2)(x_3^2+x_1^2)$.

My thoughts: I've tried $7(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)=0$ and expanded it out to match the polynomial given and got an ugly system of equations (which I can share). I'm not sure if I should start off with this equation or go a different way.

Comment: You can try the Cardano's formula

Answer (score 1):

If we define $f(x)=7(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3) = 7 x^3 + 24 x^2 + 2016 x +\imath$ with $x_i$ the three distinct roots and consider the function $g(y)$ defined by
$$
g(y)=(y-x_1^2)(y-x_2^2)(y-x_3^2)
$$
then we find that the required quantity is given by
$$
g(y=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2) = (x_2^2+x_3^2)(x_1^2+x_3^2)(x_1^2+x_2^2)
$$
Note that we also have
$$
g(x^2)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x+x_1)(x+x_2)(x+x_3)=\frac{- f(x) f(-x)}{49} = \\x^6 + \frac{27648}{49} x^4 + (82944 - \frac{48}{49} \imath) x^2 + \frac{1}{49}
$$
and hence that from the definition of $g(y)$ we know that $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 = -\frac{27649}{49}$, which gives the desired result
$$
(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_1^2+x_3^2)(x_2^2+x_3^2) = g(-\frac{27649}{49}) = -\frac{2293235711}{49} + \frac{1327104}{2401} \imath
$$
which is indeed not a particular appealing result.

An alternative path is to follow the approach of @Eclipse Sun showed. This is based on introducing $s_1=x_1+x_2+x_3$, $s_2=x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3 + x_2 x_3$, $s_3=x_1 x_2 x_3$ and realising that
$$
f(x) = 7 (x^3 - s_1 x^2 + s_2 x - s_3)
$$
You can check that:
$$
(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_1^2+x_3^2)(x_2^2+x_3^2) = s_1^2 s_2^2 - 2 s_2^2 - 2 s_1^3 s_3 + 4 s_1 s_2 s_3 - s_3^2
$$
and with the values $s_1=-24/7$, $s_2=2016/7$, and $s_3=-\imath/7$ you will find the same result as above.

Note that this is a little bit different from the solution of @Eclipse Sun, due to a small mistake $x_1^2 x_2^2 + x_1^2 x_3^2 + x_2^2 x_3^2 \neq \sigma_2^2 - \sigma_1 \sigma_3$ and which results in a wrong final answer.

Answer (score 0):

The general method is to express the symmetric polynomial $A=(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_2^2+x_3^2)(x_3^2+x_1^2)$ as a polynomial of elementary symmetric polynomials: $\sigma_1=x_1+x_2+x_3$, $\sigma_2=x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1$, $\sigma_3=x_1x_2x_3$. Then you apply [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Let's do the first step. Observe that
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=\sigma_1^2-2\sigma_2=s_2.$$
Thus, what you need is 
$$A=(s_2-x_1^2)(s_2-x_2^2)(s_2-x_3^2)=s_2^3-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)s_2^2+(x_1^2x_2^2+x_1^2x_3^2+x_1^2x_3^2)s_2-x_1^2x_2^2x_3^2.$$
The first two terms are cancelled. Then we determine 
$$x_1^2x_2^2+x_1^2x_3^2+x_2^2x_3^2=\sigma_2^2-2\sigma_1\sigma_3.$$
Hence, we get 
$$A=(\sigma_2^2-2\sigma_1\sigma_3)s_2-\sigma_3^2.$$

If you plug in all the numbers $\sigma_1=-24/7$, $\sigma_2=2016/7=288$, $\sigma_3=-i/7$, I believe it is a monster. WolframAlpha says it should be $$A=-\frac{2293235711}{49} + i\frac{2654208}{2401}.$$

Comment: Your solution is nice, but the symmetric polynomial is off, and the imaginary part should be close to (if not equal to) zero.

Comment: @HansMusgrave You may be right. The imaginary part of the roots are small, but the real part of the roots are large. I'm not sure if the result would have small imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=b_3 x^3 + b_2 x^2 + b_1 x + b_0$ be a cubic having as zeros exactly $x_1^2+x_2^2$, $x_2^2+x_3^2$, $x_3^2+x_1^2$. Then $(x_1^2+x_2^2)(x_2^2+x_3^2)(x_3^2+x_1^2)=-b_0/b_3$.

Now $x_1^2+x_2^2=p_2-x_3^2$ etc. and so the roots of $g$ are given by $h(x_i)$ where $h(x)=p_2-x^2$. Note that $p_2=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2-2(x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3 x_1)$ is easily computed from the coefficients of $f(x)=7x^3+24x^2+2016x+i$.

Finally, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_transformation) tells us that $g$ is given by the resultant $\operatorname {Res}_{x}(y-h(x),f(x))$, which you can find using WA.